# How to know the Mapreduce API in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Does anybody know how to checkout the version of Mapreduce API in hive?

when i tried to load HDFS files into hive, i have run into a problem of

```
FAILED: SemanticException 1:14 Input format must implement InputFormat.
```

I've beening searching thses days, a lot of peoples say this is because "custom format is implementing the new mapreduce InputFormat API. while Hive need an InputFormat that
implements org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat (the old API)."

So i just wondered how could i checkout out the Mapreduce API which is used by hive 0.12, any anwser will be appreciated.thanks